# How does information 'move'?

Tags: speed-of-light, information

Information cannot be transmitted faster than the light. However, I am confused about the meaning of 'transmission' of information. How does the information 'move'? If I calculate the future state of a particle using physics laws, did the information about particle 'move' with negative speed?

Answer (score 4):

Many ways. I can mail you a letter. I can point a light at you and blink it on and off in Morse code. I can throw a rock to let you know I am unhappy.

Essentially, if anything moves from A to B, and someone at B can learn something from it, information has moved.

Information cannot be transmitted faster than light because nothing that carries information can. Light is the common example. But what it means is deeper.

To transmit information to B, you must change the state of something at B. Classically, that means exert a force that moves something. Quantum mechanically, it might mean promote an atom to a excited state. Either way, forces and energy can be carried by electromagnetism or gravity. These travel at the speed of light. The other two fundamental forces, the strong and weak nuclear forces, are short range. But they would be the same.)

You can carry information by changing the motion of an object. But that requires exerting a force on it.

So there is no way to transmit information faster than light.

Answer (score 1):

You mention calculating the future state of a particle. In physics these types of calculates are often described by differential equations. To solve a differential equation you need two things:

1. The differential equation (the physical law)
2. Initial conditions (Also: boundary conditions)

Since you need initial conditions, knowing the full physics of the system is not enough. As an example, let's say Alice and Bob live on two separate planets, one lightyear apart. Alice sends a message to Bob, encoded in a photon. The message is encoded in the polarization: vertical polarization means  yes and horizontal polarization means no. But don't get distracted by the exact way this message is encoded, since it doesn't matter too much.

Bob knows a lot about physics and he can predict the way the photon evolves. Yet he has no idea what the result of the message will be. That depends on a decision made by Alice, which counts as the initial conditions.

The fact that information moves at the speed of light means that *nothing* can bring that message faster to Bob than the photon.

This fact is often described using a light cone. Imagine at one instant Alice sends photons in all possible directions. The photons all travel at $c$, so they form an ever expanding sphere. This divides space into two sections: the part inside the sphere could have received the information by Alice and the part outside cannot. The part inside is called a 'light cone', because it looks like a cone if you plot using 2 space dimensions and 1 time dimension.

Everytime an event happens, anything in the universe can only be affected by that event if it lies in the light cone of that event. As an example, if the sun were to suddenly disappear, the earth would still receive light from it for 8 minutes, because the earth is about 8 lightminutes away. *But*, it also means the earth would continue rotating around the sun for 8 more minutes, because within that time-frame the earth has no way of knowing the sun has disappeared.

I hope this helps clarify things a bit.